# MVVM combine multi data sources

Tags: c#

I collect data from different Web APIs (because I want to let users choose what source they want to use). Even if the data have same sort of information, the data models are different.

For example, one API sent this model:

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public int Code{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public Info Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("person")]
    public Info Person{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Info
{
    [JsonProperty("elementid")]
    public int ElementId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the other API sent this one:

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]           // This is corresponding to Code for previous api, it is easy to change
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }    // This one is Type.Name => type problem

    [JsonProperty("person")]           // This data exists in both models but this is not the same type 
                                       // (but i can merge Info class from the first model with the Member class)
    public Member Person{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Member
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("activity")]
    public string Activity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, I can create dummy properties for some APIs to have one unique model.

The problem is that the data models are a lot more complex than those pieces of code, and I use four sources (so, four models too).

For the moment, I use a very painful and dirty code to achieve my goal (just an example here, many lines need the same structure, `OnPropertyChanged` is defined four times !!!):

```
if (myGrid.DataContext.GetType() == typeof(Sources.SourceA) && mySourceA != null)
{
    mySourceA.IsFileSaved = true;
}
else if (myGrid.DataContext.GetType() == typeof(Sources.SourceB) && mySourceB != null)
{
    mySourceB.IsFileSaved = true;
}
else if (myGrid.DataContext.GetType() == typeof(Sources.SourceC) && mySourceC != null)
{
    mySourceC.IsFileSaved = true;
}
else if (myGrid.DataContext.GetType() == typeof(Sources.SourceD) && mySourceD != null)
{
    mySourceD.IsFileSaved = true;
}
```

Of course, what i want to obtain here, is only :

```
if (mySources != null)   // I know what model is used for DataContext !
{
    mySources.IsFileSaved = true;
}
```

My question is simple as the answer may (should?) be complex :):
How can I use only one model with multiple sources? (maybe I have not proceeded in the right way when I tried to merge all models, but i've tried in many ways)

For sure, using only one source is the simplest way, but I do not want to do that.

Thank you for your ideas... and your solutions (I hope so :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is with a strategy pattern. Create an `ISource` interface, like this:

```
namespace StrategySource
{
    public interface ISource
    {
        bool IsFileSaved { get; set; }

        // add any other common properties...
    }
}
```

Notice that the `ISource` interface contains the `IsFileSaved` property that's common to all sources. Add any other common members to this interface as you need.

Then make your classes implement this interface, like this:

```
namespace StrategySource
{
    class SourceA : ISource
    {
        private bool isFileSaved;

        // replace with your own custom implementation
        public bool IsFileSaved
        {
            get { return isFileSaved; }
            set { isFileSaved = value; }
        }
    }

    class SourceB : ISource
    {
        private bool isFileSaved;

        // replace with your own custom implementation
        public bool IsFileSaved
        {
            get { return isFileSaved; }
            set { isFileSaved = value; }
        }
    }

    // other sources ...
}
```

Each `SourceN` class implements `ISource`. That's a contract -- and because of that contract, you know that they also have an `IsFileSaved` property.

You can have as many `SourceN` classes as you want to implement `ISource`. This gives you extensibility for the future.

This lets you write the code one time, like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StrategySource
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ISource> sources = GetSources();

            foreach (var source in sources)
                if (source != null)
                    source.IsFileSaved = true;
        }

        static List<ISource> GetSources()
        {
            return new List<ISource>
            {
                new SourceA(),
                new SourceB()
                // and so on
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I used the `GetSources` to pull each of these into a collection and it sounds like you already have code that does that.

The point here is that because each of the `SourceN` classes implement the same interface, you can write a single algorithm that operates on all of them the same way. You might have heard this referred to as interface polymorphism.

Comment: It seems interesting, i have already tried with an abstract class. But, i'm stumbling on data type for some properties. eg. for one property Title : SourceA is Title, SourceB is Info.Title, SourceC is Datas.Infos.Title

Comment: A couple thing you could do in that case. If you have the ability to edit the `SourceN` files, add `Title` as a property and have that return `Info.Title`. If you can't modify `SourceN`, create a `SourceNAdapter` class that implements `ISource` with properties that access the `SourceN`.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I marked this anwser as ok. I will try this... I have some work to do :)